# Configuring SSL between Worklight adapters and back-end servers

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

Is there anyway that Worklight adapters ignore a self-signed certificate's expiration date from a web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WL server will not work with expired certificates. You will have to create a new certificate and add it to the keystore WL server uses.